# Javascript/Typescript - replace user ID with user name in view

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `car` model. Each `car` has a `userid` on it. Each `user` model has a `userid` and a `username`.

I want to display all of my `car` models in my view, with their associated `username`. I am having a hard time finding out how to convert the `userid` to a `username` without storing `username` on the `car` model. My code looks like this:

```
navigatedTo() {
    this.carsRepository.getCars().then((cars) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; ++i) {
            var car = cars[i];
            this.usersRepository.getUsers().then(() => {
                car.username = this.usersRepository.findUserById(car.userid).then(() => {
                    console.log(car);
                });
            });
        }
        this.context.cars = cars;
    });
}
```

The idea is that once you navigate to a page, you'll hit `navigatedTo` and then I will loop through `this.context.cars`. The issue with the above code is that `car.username` doesn't exist. It's not an attribute on `car`.

How can I use typescript/javascript to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you doing with the data once it's been gathered? There are lots of options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guidance is to have a seperate UI model for a car e.g. UICar which contains the Car model. I.e.

```
interface UICar
{
     car:Car;
     username:string;
}
```

And then map the server request to a UICar object. Expose the ui cars on the context.

Comment: Often called a "view model".

Comment: @WiredPrairie sort of. But this is a sub view model (`context.cars`) of the view model (`context`)